# How to navigate to login module from feature module in multi module compose project

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation, android-multi-module

I'm working on a multi module compose project where I'm having difficulty navigating from one module to another the module dependancy is follows as bellow:

- common module (common ui component for whole app)
- app module (having dependancy of common, login and other features - knows about every module in the project)
- login module (having dependancy of common module)
- feature 1 module (having dependancy of common module)
- feature 2 module (having dependancy of common module)

I need to navigate to login from feature 1 or 2 when logout and vice versa when logout, circular dependancy error is coming, please help

P.S
Im not using any DI, or is it necessary to use DI?

Comment: the way to navigate is use the app module as a common place. after login hoist state to app module and then navigate to feature 2. Nowinandroid samples does that. https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/tree/main/app and the docs also says you need mediating module in this case it could be app module https://developer.android.com/topic/modularization/patterns